# How to cut down ActiveSync functionality on Windows CE device

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, activesync

Is there any way to cut down a specific functions of ActiveSync service on Windows CE device?

I want to see only one specific folder on my device when it's connected to PC.

Basically I want to leave only functionality of exchanging data via a specific folder, without any other communication (deploying applications, synchronization etc.).

I'm using a device with Windows CE 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveSync really only has 2 "modes" - either with the ability to sync PIM info, or just the ability to connect as Guest.  In both modes a user can browse the device from the PC.

What it sounds like you want to do is not include ActiveSync at all, but instead make your device a USB function device that acts as Mass Storage.  If you do that you can then set a specific folder to be the mounted store and they would have access to only that folder.

Of course in that scenario you can't use any of the PIM data sync features.

Comment: I can switch to Mass Storage mode, but it doesn't suit me because when the device is connected to PC, the drives are unavailable for windows CE

Comment: Then you're going to have to write a custom driver.  ActiveSync won't do what you want.